# Question about CheckBox in Java in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a project in Android Studio, in which there is a small home screen with a button. When a user clicks this button on the home screen, the application must go to another screen, which contains several checkboxes.

However, I am having two problems:

1. The code accesses the main page. But when you click on a button to go to another page, the application leaves the screen instead of going to another page. I already put the name of the method that is on another page, which I want you to execute, in the onclick attribute but it still doesn't work.
2. I would like that after a user clicks on a button that is on the home screen, opens a screen that contains several checkboxes (this screen is already made). Each check box contains a value. When a user clicks on a checkbox, I created a variable that adds up.
   When the user clicks on the checkboxes the user wants, and after the user clicks the send button, the sum of the checkbox values ​​will appear in a textView.

This is the checkbox code:

```
       int result = 0;
       private CheckBox blue;
       private CheckBox red;
       private CheckBox yellow;
       private CheckBox green;
       private CheckBox black;
       private CheckBox white;
       private CheckBox orange;
       private CheckBox purple;
       private CheckBox gray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.id.interfacegraphicalname);

       blue = findViewById(R.id.blue);
       red = findViewById(R.id.red);
       yellow = findViewById(R.id.yellow);
       green = findViewById(R.id.green);
       black = findViewById(R.id.black);
       white = findViewById(R.id.white);
       orange = findViewById(R.id.orange);
       purple = findViewById(R.id.purple);
       gray = findViewById(R.id.gray);
       testFinalResult(result);
       }

public void check() {
       if (blue.isChecked()) {
              result += 30;
       } else if (red.isChecked()) {
              result += 30;
       } else if (green.isChecked()) {
              result += 30;
       } else ig (yellow.isChecked()) {
              result += 20;
       } else if (black.isChecked()) {
              result += 20;
       } else if (white.isChecked()) {
              result +=20;
       } else if (orange.isChecked()) {
              result += 10;
       } else if (purple.isChecked()) {
              result += 10;
       } else if (gray.isChecked()) {
       result +=10;
       }
       int testResult = check();

public void finalTestResult(int testResult) {
       if (testResult <= 60) {
              finalResultText.setText("low value");
       } else if (testResult <= 120) {
              finalResultText.setText("medium value");
       } else if (testResult<= 180) {
       finalResultText.setText("high value");
       }
}
}
```

But as the code contains one more error that when you click a button on the home screen, the application is not going to the next screen for some reason, I would like to show you all the code (which is too much big to insert here on Stack OverFlow) for you to check out what is going wrong, that I'm not able to run the code normally at all, ok?

Please, could you check?

I've been working on this project for a long time, and I'm not getting the code to run normally on the smartphone.
The code link is:

https://github.com/AvaianoFC1/OficialTestProject

Answer (score 1):

/Checked out your code on github here is my initial findings
hopefully it will help you resolve your issue in your Calc.java class you need to setcontentview to entries layout instead of referring back to main layout*/

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   setContentView(R.layout.entries);
```

you are referring back to main activity layout which only has the layout for one button, so your button is working but its taking you back to activity main - you need to display entries layout and get all your values from that layout and then move ahead accordingly

another error from my inital lookup that i noticed is this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:onClick="sendMessage2"
    android:text="OPEN PAGE 2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.647"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.237" />
```

android:onClick="sendMessage2" -> you are calling the sendMessage2 function which you have not defined you need to call the **openPage2** function

also you do not need the openPage1 and openPage2 in your main activity class

Let me know if this helps you these are the few errors that are flatout - also i would recommend adding a snackbar or a toast message on button click before implementing the functionality just to make sure thats its working as intended